# Flutter Navigator.push : .then callback not called

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, callback

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => SubscriptionFenRoute())).then((value) {
    print("passing");
    refreshState();
});
```

The .then callback is never called when doing `Navigator.pop(context)`. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you post any errors you're receiving? What you're doing looks correct and I'm able to achieve similar behavior.

Comment: That's the thing, there's no errors. But I noticed a difference : I have a global object displayed & modified in SubscriptionFenRoute. When I add a new one, it does go into the callback and everything works fine. When I'm editing one, it doesn't, even if I make a new instance.
To note : The parent Scaffold has ListView as body, and each ListTile has 'key' set to ObjectKey(subscriptions[index]). I also tried with UniqueKey(), no luck.